# How does a sequence's convergency change finite sums?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

What has been troubling me lately is that I cannot grasp how a finite series could ever diverge if a finite sequence that is divergent can only imply to a finite sum every time.

Perhaps my main question is why divergent sequences even matter compared to convergent sequences.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: A finite sum can't diverge. A finite sequence can't diverge. Divergent sequences, and divergent series, matter, because they are occasionally the natural outcome of some calculation. If you do a calculation, and a divergent sequence or series emerges from your calculation, then divergent series matter to you.

Answer (score 0):

If for "finite series" you are thinking at a series $a_n$ whose terms are bounded (and tending to zero) maybe it would help you to consider the associate sequence $s_n = \sum_0^n(a_n)$. Of course if you stop at any step you have a finite sum, but the sum will eventually exceed any fixed value.

The importance of the distinction between a divergent and a convergent series is that with the latter you actually have a definite number (even if you don't know what it is), while with the former you cannot use the usual formal arithmetic operations, and you have to check step by step what you are doing.